# Blazor Server Monaco DiffEditor setup

Tags: server, blazor, monaco-editor

I'm trying to set up Monaco Diff Editor but of the life of me I cannot figure out the syntax to have it started. A single instance of Monaco works just fine but the DiffEditor is beyond me.  Below you can find my code, I left the StandaloneEditorConstructionOptions because I suspect it will be needed for originalEditor and Modified editor but I cannot figure out how to set them up to show my sample json code. Anyone done this?

```
@using BlazorMonaco;

<ErrorBoundary>
    <div class="padding" style="height:10rem">
        <MonacoDiffEditor Id="diffEdit" @ref="diffEditor" ConstructionOptions="DiffConstructionOptions" CssClass="monaco_h" />
    </div>
</ErrorBoundary>
```

@code {

```
MonacoDiffEditor diffEditor { get; set; }

string? string1 = "sample_json";
string? string2 = "sample_json_2";

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await SetEditors();
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
}

private static StandaloneEditorConstructionOptions EditorConstructionOptions(MonacoEditor editor)
{
    return new StandaloneEditorConstructionOptions()
    {
        AutomaticLayout = true,
        Language = "JSON"
    };
}

private DiffEditorConstructionOptions DiffConstructionOptions(MonacoDiffEditor editor)
{
    return new DiffEditorConstructionOptions()
    {
        AutomaticLayout = true,
        OriginalEditable = false,
        ReadOnly = true
    };
}

async Task SetEditors()
{

    await diffEditor.OriginalEditor.SetValue(string1);

    await diffEditor.ModifiedEditor.SetValue(string2);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Instead of setting value you need to set model.

```
<MonacoDiffEditor @ref="diffEditor" ConstructionOptions="DiffConstructionOptions" />

@code{
MonacoDiffEditor diffEditor { get; set; }
bool editorVisible = false;

private DiffEditorConstructionOptions DiffConstructionOptions(MonacoDiffEditor editor)
{
    return new DiffEditorConstructionOptions()
    {
        // your options
    };
}

async Task SetDiffEditor(string jsonString1, string jsonString2)
{
    TextModel textModel1 = await MonacoEditor.CreateModel(jsonString1, "application/json");
    TextModel textModel2 = await MonacoEditor.CreateModel(jsonString2, "application/json");

    await diffEditor.OriginalEditor.SetModel(textModel1);
    await diffEditor.ModifiedEditor.SetModel(textModel2);
}
}
```

Upon triggering SetDiffEditor() both editor panes appear and depending on options you selected shows you the formatted code with differences between panes.

Comment: Hey, can you share how you set up your _Layouts.cshtml file? There's very few people using this with blazor.server so it might help someone else too, like me :-)

Comment: @gciochina sorry, haven't been here in a while. I haven't done any setup in the Layout.cshtml. Everything is done within the razor component file. I'm still using it so if you need any help let me know.